# Need Asistance with Debugging

Tags: python, debugging, syntax-error

I am new to Python and I need to use it as a calculator for a lab report. I am using it simply as a calculator, for the convenience and easy debugging that comes with scripting languages. I typed this into the python shell, but, for some reason when I press enter, it just starts a new line. This only happens in the last line. Am I using the wrong syntax?

> > > mCupWater = 131.6
> > >
> > > mCupWaterIce = 153.1
> > >
> > > mITemp = 49
> > >
> > > mFTemp = 29
> > >
> > > mCup = 3.7
> > >
> > > mWater = mCupWater - mCup
> > >
> > > c = 4.181
> > >
> > > mIceWater = mCupWaterIce - mCup
> > >
> > > l = ((mWater * c * (mITemp - mFTemp)) - (mIceWater * c * (mFTemp)) / (mIceWater)

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot a bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing `)`.  There is implicit line continuation within parentheses, brackets and braces.